# PowerEdge FX2s ram types

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge, infrastructure, blade-server

I have a PowerEdge FX2s modular server with two PowerEdge FC630 Blades.

Does the RAM type in both blades need to be identical in terms of:

2133P / 2400T ?

Ranks ?

Module sizes symmetry ?

I am new in Blade servers.

Nees Assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Configs can be different, just make sure all the components (RAM, disks, and so on) are within the vendor blessed specs.

Blade servers are like normal servers, just power, network, and sometimes storage connectors are proprietary for the purpose you could pack many mostly compute-only nodes within the minimum rack space.